# Import datetime in one column of txt-files

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial, read.csv

How do I import the datetime column correctly? date+time in one column as as DATE

I have got a txt-file with columns: seriesnumber, time and temperature.

I tried:

```
test.c <- read.csv("110.txt", header = F,skip = 26, sep = "",  dec = ",", col.names = "Seriennummer","Zeit","Temperatur°C")
```

However, this always gives me:

[image]

This is how the data looks like in the editor:

[image]

Data:

```
readLines("8.txt",n=10)

 [1] "Seriennummer                      Zeit\tTemperaturÂ°C"
 [2] "         1           16.03.2023 15:17:33      26,8"  
 [3] "         2           16.03.2023 15:18:33        27"  
 [4] "         3           16.03.2023 15:19:33      26,8"  
 [5] "         4           16.03.2023 15:20:33      26,3"  
 [6] "         5           16.03.2023 15:21:33        26"  
 [7] "         6           16.03.2023 15:22:33      25,5"  
 [8] "         7           16.03.2023 15:23:33      25,3"  
 [9] "         8           16.03.2023 15:24:33      25,1"  
[10] "         9           16.03.2023 15:25:33      24,9"
```

Comment: Looks like your data is tab-separated: does `read.csv(..., sep = "\t", ...)` help?

Comment: This gives me just one column that stores all 3 columns...

Comment: could you add the output of ``readLines("8.txt",n=4)`` in your question ?

Comment: It would be better if as much of your example as possible were in text format rather than images.

Comment: Edited that it's at the end now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.fwf` (read fixed-width fields) should work well, but you would have to count characters in the line to determine the appropriate `widths=` argument (it's too hard to tell from the image you posted).

I don't think base R converts to date-time formats automatically, but `readr::read_fwf()` (which is similar to `read.fwf` but a little more flexible) might.  It's *possible* that it will correctly "guess... based on the positions of empty columns" (the default), you could try it ...

It looks like this works (guessing doesn't work because it wants to split date and time again ... I used a column-number-aware text editor to figure out the appropriate start/end positions for each field)

```r
library(readr)
read_fwf("fwf.txt", 
         ## doesn't seem to handle header, and TAB in
         ## header might be problematic anyway ...
         skip = 1,
         ## feel free to use German names instead ...
         fwf_cols(n = c(9,10),
                  datetime = c(21,40),
                  temp = c(46,50)),
         locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read in the file line-wise, store the lines as a dataframe column and then use {tidyr}'s `separate` function to split the text into columns using two-or-more-blanks as a separator (so that the datetime which contains only one blank doesn't get split):

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(data = readLines('path_to_your_file.csv')) |>
  separate(data,
           sep = '[ \t]{2,}', ## at least 2 blanks/tabs needed to split by
           into = c('Seriennummer', 'Zeit', 'Temperatur')
           )
```

Comment: Thx. Played around with it but didn´t work correctly. I think the reason is the difference in blanks between "Zeit" and "Temperatur".